# The wday functionality in lubridate

Tags: r

Could someone explain in simple terms what wday in R does.

E.g:

```
df$date[wday(df$date, week_start=1)==7] <- df$date[wday(df$date, week_start=1)==7]-1
```

Comment: It basically says from the column date, set the values as weekdays starting from 1 and find the 7th day. Then `<-` replace those days by `days-1`

Comment: the `wday()` most likely origins from the `lubridate`-package (although `data.table` also contains a function named wday()). I suggest you read it's helpfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the wday function from the package "lubridate", it takes a date and returns the day of the week that date fell on:

```
> library(lubridate)
> date = as.Date('1592-03-14')
> wday(date)
[1] 7
```

It has options to change the first day of the week, and to give output in words instead:

```
> library(lubridate)
> date = as.Date('1592-03-14')
> wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
[1] Saturday
7 Levels: Sunday < Monday < ... < Saturday
>
> wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, week_start = 1)
[1] Saturday
7 Levels: Monday < Tuesday < ... < Sunday
```

Basic function information like this is readily available in a package's [documentation](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/day.html) to save having to wait for an answer in future.